# AS3: Tutorial on how to get started creating a game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, actionscript

I'm a fairly new programmer with some background in AS2, C#, and Java. What I tried to do was begin creating a game in AS3 and simply consult Google when necessary, but there are some significant changes combined with my inexperience that are making things difficult.

Basically, I have a grid-layout successfully working where you can control a movieclip on the grid and within the bounds. I also implemented a 2D-Array class to create an array that could mimic the board and store information like "There is already a character at position 5,4 so you cannot move your character there." It just stores 0's and 1's.

What I'm lost at is how to correctly manage the movieclips I created in my library so they could be placed on the stage and be handled by already-written code. By this I mean it would be fantastic to add a movieclip and have an event handler updating my 2D array to say that location has been filled now. As well as add some AI movement to it that I maybe had a class for.

So in a nutshell, I was wondering if anyone had either some quick tips or tutorials that could help me get the ball rolling again.

Thanks!!

Mike

Comment: Could you provide some pseudo code to illustrate what you're trying to do?  or is just as simple as needing to know how to instantiate an object from your library via code?

Comment: Yeah, I responded to what I thought you wanted. Let me know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to link an AS3 class to the MovieClip. Essentially, you right-click on the movie clip in your library. Bring up Properties and select `Export for ActionScript`. Either type in a new class name or one you have already written.

Then, all you have to do is create a new instance of it. To add things to the stage, simply use `addChild(myMovieClip)` once you have them positioned nicely.

You will have to add them at runtime in order to pass in parameters such as the array (unless you just reference the stage from within classes). Just make sure the linked classes extend MovieClip.

Also take a gander at this website: [AS Tutorial Basics](http://asgamer.com/2009/flash-game-design-basics-adding-library-objects-to-stage-with-as3)

Hope this helps and good luck! I hated the transition to AS3.0 too.

Comment: Thanks Thikan! I would upvote your answer if I had enough reputation but unfortunately this is my first post :)

I've attached my AI class to a movieclip now and I was able to create a new instance of that movieclip by running:
 var Green:AI = new AI(x,y); //constructor takes coordinates
 addChild(Green);

I seem to be a little confused now as to how I would go about attaching multiple movieclips to the same AI class. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, very possible. Just keep doing `var varName:Ai = new AI(x,y);` Then add them all. I would suggest putting them all into an Array to keep track of them, then iterate through to add them to the stage.

Comment: Hi Thikan, thanks for the help again. Sorry, my last question was a little misleading. I meant is it possible to export multiple different movieclips from my library to the same class. So if I created two movieclips A and B, could I attach my AI class to both?